# Not able to write output in the excel using selenium code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
public class AustriaRegro {
    public String Result;
    WebDriver driver;
    WebDriverWait wait;
    Sheet s;
    WritableSheet ws;
    WritableWorkbook wc;
    Workbook w;

    @Test
    public void TestSetup()  throws IOException, BiffException, RowsExceededException, WriteException{
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\UAT WEBSHOP.xls");
        w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
        s = w.getSheet("Regro");
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\yirsh\\Desktop\\UATWEBSHOPResult.xls");
        wc =Workbook.createWorkbook(fo);
        ws = wc.createSheet("Query_data", 0);
        Sheet sheets = w.getSheet("Query_data");
        String inputdata[] [] = new String[s.getRows()][s.getColumns()];
        for (int i=0;i<s.getRows();i++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k< s.getColumns();k++)
            {
                inputdata[i][k] = s.getCell(k,i).getContents();
                Label l = new Label(k,i , inputdata[i][k]);
                Label la = new Label(4,0,"Results");
                ws.addCell(l);
                ws.addCell(la);
            }
        }
        for(int row=1; row <= s.getRows() ; row++){
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("http://path/");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            String username = s.getCell(2,row).getContents();
            System.out.println("***********************************");
            System.out.println("Username: "+username);

            driver.findElement(By.id("j_username_leftAside")).sendKeys(username);
            String password= s.getCell(3,row).getContents();
            System.out.println("Password: "+password);
            driver.findElement(By.id("j_password_leftAside")).sendKeys(password);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html[@class=' js opacity generatedcontent pointerevents']/body[@class='page-homepage pageType-ContentPage template-pages-layout-RexelHomePageLayout pageLabel-homepage language-de ']/div[@id='page']/div[@id='content']/div[@id='content']/div[@class='content-top-inner']/div[@id='content-inner']/div[@class='mid-wrapper'][1]/div[@class='yCmsContentSlot']/div[@class='login clear']/form[@id='loginForm']/div[@class='left sign-in']/button[@class='Sign-in rx-btn mb0']")).click();

            try{
                if((driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div"))).isDisplayed()){
                    System.out.println("Login Failed");
                    Result="Failed";
                    String Error=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='globalMessages']/div")).getText();
                    System.out.println("The Error mesaage is :"+Error);
                    System.out.println("***********************************************************************************************************");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println("Login Sucessfull");
                Result="Pass";
                System.out.println("***********************************");
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='content-inner']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/ul/li[9]/a")).click();
            }
            Label lb = new Label(4,1,Result);
            ws.addCell(lb);
        }
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I am writing a code to fetch data from an excel sheet and run selenium tests on it and write the output in a different excel file. Result Excel has been created but data is not inserted.Need to correct the code so that it can insert the results.Only saving the result in excel is pending remaining all working fine as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write to file. I believe you can do so by calling  `WritableWorkbook.write()`. Remember to close the files afterward.

```
...
    ...
    Label lb = new Label(4,1,Result);
    ws.addCell(lb);
}
wc.write();
wc.close();
w.close();
driver.close();
```

See the [documentation here](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html#write()). The write function can throw an IOException, so you'll have to handle that at some point - I see you're passing that exception up the stack, that's fine.